# Magento-Varnish best VCL configuration

Tags: apache, magento, varnish, varnish-vcl

I have installed Varnish accelerator with Apache webserver for Magento installation. 
Can any body suggest the best default.vcl (/etc/varnish/default.vcl) configuration for this ? 
Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Obiously you didn't Google this, atleast look for the solution yourself before you come to SO.

When I googled "Magento Varnish" I came up with this first links that is a FREE extension that contains the default.vcl file that you need:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/pagecache-powered-by-varnish.html

Comment: I had done a much Googling in this regard; the above given link is a Magento Module for optimization with Vanish. Before using any of such modules I must configure Varnish for Magento, correctly; because there are many locations ( such as admin, checkout etc.) we don't want to cache pages.
In one of my previous Magento installations, the below page helped me for setting up:
http://pastebin.com/W0gQ2sze
But now, it seems to be not working, then through Googling I found latest Varnish version does not support some of the tags given in along with this.

Comment: .
Varnish version: 3.0.2
Os: CentOS 5
Configuraiton files:
/etc/sysconfig/varnish
/etc/varnish/default.vcl

Comment: If you download the module you will see that there is a default.vcl included custom for Magento.

Answer (score 0):

If google did still guide you here:

Magento does by now offer a default VCL files within the depths of their GIT repository.

for Varnish 4.x
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/PageCache/etc/varnish4.vcl

for Varnish 5.x
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/PageCache/etc/varnish5.vcl

for Varnish 6.x
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/777b0b0a0950b819991fda239793c91c966254be/app/code/Magento/PageCache/etc/varnish6.vcl